# How can I associate multiple accounts to a single opportunity?

Tags: relationships

We are a company who sells to both individual companies (One opportunity to one account) and to companies with branch offices (One opportunity with multiple accounts).  Is there a way to associate a single opportunity with multiple customer account records?

Comment: How about creating lookup on Account to opportunity ?

Answer (score 2):

@Test Sfdc A many-to-many relationship consists of three objects: Object A and Object B are the two primary objects, and Object J is the junction that enables the many to many. Object A <--M/D-- Object J --M/D--> Object B So on Object J you need to create two Master-Detail relationships, one that points to Object A and one that points to Object B

please check this URL: https://success.salesforce.com/apex/answers?id=90630000000ZfRRAA0

Comment: You could add some description on what explained in that link.

Comment: Update description using [edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/161111/edit) your post

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Junction object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_manytomany.htm&language=en&type=0) between Account and Opportunity to let one-Opp relate to many Accounts.

Please note that your new junction object would be a child of Both Account and Opportunity, so any customization that you may have need to reviewed in order to display related information.

Answer (score -1):

Go to account page layout and add other opportunities related list
for creating  many to many relationship between Account and opportunity 
first create lookup with account in opportunity how many you want and then just add those opportunities in account page layout

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question being asked. It does not seem to provide a clear solution to the problem at hand.